# Why does Google Guava offer static methods where equivalent constructors exist?

Tags: java, constructor, guava

I noticed that [Google Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) [`Sets`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) class offers methods such as [`newHashSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newHashSet(java.lang.Iterable)) taking an `Iterable` or `Iterator`. The [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) class bundled with Java already offers a constructor taking a `Collection` thereby giving similar behavior.

So I am curious… What is the advantage of these particular static methods in Guava Sets? Is it simply that there may be `Iterable` or `Iterator` objects that are *not* also a `Collection`? Or is there some other purpose to the Guava team bothering to include such methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Google Guava docs, [CollectionUtilitiesExplained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained):

> Whenever possible, Guava prefers to provide utilities accepting an `Iterable` rather than a `Collection`. Here at Google, it's not out of the ordinary to encounter a "collection" that isn't actually stored in main memory, but is being gathered from a database, or from another data center, and can't support operations like `size()` without actually grabbing all of the elements.
>
> As a result, many of the operations you might expect to see supported for all collections can be found in `Iterables`. Additionally, most `Iterables` methods have a corresponding version in `Iterators` that accepts the raw iterator.
>
> The overwhelming majority of operations in the `Iterables` class are lazy: they only advance the backing iteration when absolutely necessary. Methods that themselves return `Iterables` return lazily computed views, rather than explicitly constructing a collection in memory.

Comment: So that does answer the part of my Question about “Are there `Iterable` objects that are not a `Collection`?”. Yes, indeed, there are. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`Iterable` interface was introduced in Java 1.5 and is a base interface for `Collection` interface

`HashSet` constructor predates this modification, and I think for compatibility they've left it as is in Java 1.5

Guava, on the other hand was not restricted by this change, and for convenience provides constructor that takes `Iterator`.

By default `Iterable` constructor tries to cast `Iterable` to `Collection` and if it's not possible, falls through to extracting its `Iterator` and calling `Iterator` constructor.

In my view, this gives better flexibility to library users.

One other reason for the existence of `Sets` utility class was the long hand writing required in Java 1.5 and 1.6 when calling generic constructors.

This particular issue was solved in 1.7 by introducing diamond operator.

To illustrate.

Before 1.7

```
ArrayList<String> myList = ...
// See generic parameter repeated
HashSet<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>( myList );
// No such issue for statics
HashSet<String> myGuavaSet = Sets.newHashSet( myList );
```

After 1.7

```
ArrayList<String> myList = ...
// Notice diamond
HashSet<String> mySet = new HashSet<>( myList );
// Really no reason now to use Guava for HashSet construction in most cases
```